# Change Opacity in Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to change the opacity of the hover effect at http://3e6.864.myftpupload.com/. I tried changing the opacity in CSS, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
}
```

Comment: please provide the code you have tried.

Comment: .isotope .isotope-item {
filter: alpha(opacity=90); 
opacity: 0.9;
 -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
   -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
}

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to achieve this effect on hover of the element you need to use the `:hover` selector in your CSS and set the `transition` attribute:

```
.isotope .isotope-item:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvp6bLky/1/)

Comment: as a side note, you should always place the proprietary IE syntax crap at the **bottom** of the CSS statement rather than the top. Older versions of webkit would blow up if you didn't.